# Symfony 5 - Use different host for environment (dev, prod)

Tags: php, symfony, routes, environment, host

in my Symfony 5 project, I am looking to use different subdomains for my controllers depending on the environment I am in (dev, prod).

For this, I created:

```
config/routes/dev/annotations.yaml
```

and

```
config/routes/prod/annotations.yaml
```

Each file contains its own host for my controllers.

**config/routes/dev/annotations.yaml**:

```
blog_controllers:
    resource: ../../../src/Controller/BlogController.php
    type: annotation
    host: 'blog.{domain}'
    defaults:
      domain: '%domain%'
    requirements:
      domain: '%domain%'

app_controllers:
    resource: ../../../src/Controller/HomeController.php
    type: annotation
    host: 'app.{domain}'
    defaults:
      domain: '%domain%'
    requirements:
      domain: '%domain%|www.%domain%'
```

**config/routes/prod/annotations.yaml:**

```
blog_controllers:
    resource: ../../../src/Controller/BlogController.php
    type: annotation
    host: 'prod.blog.{domain}'
    defaults:
        domain: '%domain%'
    requirements:
        domain: '%domain%'
```

The `%domain%` is the APP_DOMAIN in my .env, no problem with that.

So, when I'm on `prod environment`, when I'm trying to access `https://prod.blog.[myDomain]` (the homepage on my blog project part), I'm redirected on the homepage of the `HomeController`. I don't know why...

My controllers :

**BlogController.php:**

```
class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="blog")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**HomeController.php:**

```
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

edit:

I tested with this configuration :

Just in prod, set this route in the **/config/prod/annotations.yaml**

```
blog_controllers:
    resource: ../../../src/Controller/BlogController.php
    type: annotation
    host: 'blog.{domain}'
    defaults:
        domain: '%domain%'
    requirements:
        domain: '%domain%'
```

No host for dev environment.

So, on prod environment, if I make a **debug:router**, I've :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So both routes here are correct.

On the one hand, the "home" route without a subdomain, accessible by http s://myDomain.com

and on the other, the "blog" route accessible by http s://blog.myDomain.com

Are we OK?

But when I launch http://blog.myDomain.com/, It's the Home controller which is displayed !

EDIT 2 : Okay I found the solution.

Just add host for "home" route, like this :

```
app_controllers:
    resource: ../../../src/Controller/HomeController.php
    type: annotation
    host: '{domain}'
    defaults:
      domain: '%domain%'
    requirements:
      domain: '%domain%|www.%domain%'
```

No subdomain. It works.

Thanks all !
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPJlN.png

Comment: This looks fine, so 2 questions: Did you remove config/routes/annotations.yaml ? Have you tried running debug:router to make sure everything is in order?

Comment: No I didn't remove `config/routes/annotations.yaml`, and yes, I checked with `debug.router`, there is my `blog` route with the good host and the good path. It's.. weird

Comment: whats the output of `bin/console router:match https://prod.blog.[myDomain] --env=prod`?

Comment: How do you set APP_ENV? Do you do it based on vhost, or just in the .env file? Are you sure that the correct environment is loaded for each URL?

Comment: It's the .env file that I use for APP_ENV @Padam87
simon.ro, this line give me an error

I updated my first post with an example of what I have

Comment: It's good I understood the problem! In fact I absolutely had to define a host for the "home" route, although I didn't want to put a subdomain. So in my annotations.yaml file, I just defined {domain} for the home route